# A suitable game of life seed for testing

Tags: seed, conways-game-of-life, seeding

I have just finished creating a game of life simulation for c# and found one of the most confusing aspects was whether the seed I was using would actually work.

The following are seeds that can be used to ensure that your game of life is working:

```
        //two island pseudo still life
        [2, 1] [3, 1]        [5, 1] [6, 1]
               [3, 2]        [5, 2]
               [3, 3]        [5, 3]
        [2, 4] [3, 4]        [5, 4] [6, 4]

        //hacker emblem
        [1, 3]
        [2, 1]
        [2, 3]
        [3, 2]
        [3, 3]
```

The two island pseudo still life should not change.

The hacker emblem should mutate and crawl from top left to bottom right until it hits the corner.

Has anyone got anything better?

Comment: I needed this for my three.js game of life experiment. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this answer is the best for now, i'm happy to update it if anyone replies with anything at all.